# Node.js Merge 2 pdf files into one by each page

Tags: node.js, pdf

js developer.
I want to merge 2 pdf files by combining each page from 2 files.
If anyone know the solution, then please let me know.
Thanks.

I tried pdf-lib, hummus...
However I found only merging of all pages instead of combining.

Comment: I want to combine each page instead of merging all pages.
For example, pdf A has one page of text "AAA" and pdf B has one page of text "BBB", the merged pdf should have one page of text "AAA" and "BBB"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean combining each page alternately from both files?

In that case, by using `pdf-lib`, you might be able to handle the merging of pages manually, for example:

```
const { PDFDocument, rgb } = require('pdf-lib');
const fs = require('fs');

async function mergePDFs(pdfPath1, pdfPath2, outputPath) {
  const pdfDoc1 = await PDFDocument.load(fs.readFileSync(pdfPath1));
  const pdfDoc2 = await PDFDocument.load(fs.readFileSync(pdfPath2));

  const mergedPdf = await PDFDocument.create();

  const [firstPages, secondPages] = await Promise.all([
    mergedPdf.copyPages(pdfDoc1, [0, pdfDoc1.getPageCount()]),
    mergedPdf.copyPages(pdfDoc2, [0, pdfDoc2.getPageCount()]),
  ]);

  firstPages.forEach(page => mergedPdf.addPage(page));
  secondPages.forEach(page => mergedPdf.addPage(page));

  const mergedPdfBytes = await mergedPdf.save();

  fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, mergedPdfBytes);
  console.log('PDFs merged successfully!');
}

// usage:
mergePDFs('file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf', 'merged.pdf');
```

This loads both PDF files, and then adds each page alternately from both files into a new PDF document, then it saves the merged PDF to the specified output file.

Comment: I want to combine each page instead of merging all pages.
For example, pdf A has one page of text "AAA" and pdf B has one page of text "BBB", the merged pdf should have one page of text "AAA" and "BBB"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).